# Textmate Clone for Windows?

Tags: language-agnostic

Havent checked in a while but is there any good text editors out there. I have tryed e-text editor and sublime. They are perfect, but I want something with more features but not as bloated as notepad+

Comment: ideally i would love a coda clone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend [Vim](http://www.vim.org/)

Comment: you're not the first one to mention that. Hmmmm. I think i might bite the bullet and try it.

Comment: @madphp Its main benefit is you can do everything from the keyboard.  At first you will be tempted to use the mouse but it will pass in time.  It took me about two weeks to get really comfortable using it as it takes time to learn the commands.  Without having to reach for the mouse things become faster as well.

Comment: it doesnt get away from the fact that its a console window.

Comment: You can also use gvim (which comes in the package) It provides menus and buttons to also help make the transition that much easier (makes it less console like).

Answer (score 0):

e and sublime are your best bets. Both take TextMate bundles, and work well. I marginally prefer e.